# How do I match escaped characters in groups in Java RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I'm recently working on a command line project in java and I need to parse through commands. But I'm having issues in matching this particular command.

```
15.00|GR,LQ,MD "Uber"
```

where the amount can be with a decimal fraction of two or an int. I need to collect all the information on groups. "Uber" is an optional description.

Here is what I have tried..

```
Pattern.compile("ˆ([\\d]+(\\.[\\d]{2})?\\|([A-Z]{2}){1})(,[A-Z]{2})*\\s(\\\".+\\\")?$");
```

What I expect is to get the number, the two character composed users and optionally the description too..

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It does not work..

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Because this doesn't get triggered like the others. else if(pay.find()){
   System.out.println("Pay");

Comment: Have you tried`...(\".+\")...` already? I do not think that you need escape the `"` for the regexp, you just escape it for the Java string.

Comment: Do the `[` and `]` belong to the string to match?

Comment: It doesn't work because: 1) The input starts with `[`, but the regex says it has to start with digit or uppercase letter. --- 2) A `(X)*` repeating capture group will only capture the last value, so you won't get what you want.

Comment: I think the problem is the first part, the number. Since having only .compile("ˆ([\\d]+(\\.[\\d]{2})?") does not work either

Comment: [ and ] i only put here to confine my commands spaces from the rest of the text

Comment: so @Andreas , what do you suggest the regex for this should look like ?

Comment: @iSpark You can't get a dynamic set of capture groups in a regex. A regex always captures a fixed number of groups. Capture all the extra double-letters in a single group, then use `split(",")` on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex analyzed:

> ```
> "ˆ([\\d]+(\\.[\\d]{2})?\\|([A-Z]{2}){1})(,[A-Z]{2})*\\s(\\\".+\\\")?$"
> ```

First, let's un-escape the Java string literal into the actual regex string:

```
ˆ([\d]+(\.[\d]{2})?\|([A-Z]{2}){1})(,[A-Z]{2})*\s(\".+\")?$
```

Now lets split it apart:

```
ˆ                  Incorrect character 'ˆ', should be '^'
                   Match start of input, but your input starts with '['
(                  
  [\d]+            The '[]' is superfluous, use '\d+'
  (\.[\d]{2})?     Don't capture this, use '(?:X)?'
  \|
  ([A-Z]{2}){1}    The '{1}` is superfluous, and don't capture just this
)                  You're capturing too much. Move back to before '\|'
(,[A-Z]{2})*       Will only capture last ',XX'.
                   Use a capture group around all the letters, then split that on ','
\s
(\".+\")?          No need to escape '"', and only capture the content
$                  Match end of input, but your input ends with ']'
```

So, cleaned up it will be:

```
^\[
(
  \d+
  (?:\.[\d]{2})?
)
\|
(
  [A-Z]{2}
  (?:,[A-Z]{2})*
)
\s
(?:"(.+)")?
\]$
```

Joined back together:

```
^\[(\d+(?:\.[\d]{2})?)\|([A-Z]{2}(?:,[A-Z]{2})*)\s(?:"(.+)")?\]$
```

With input `[15.00|GR,LQ,MD "Uber"]` that will capture:

1. `15.00` - The full number
2. `GR,LQ,MD` - Use `split(",")` to get array `{ "GR", "LQ", "MD" }`
3. `Uber` - Just the text without the quotes

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nwlQ7a/1) on regex101.com.

Answer (score 2):

The first character is a `ˆ` and not `^`. Beside that you should change your first group to `([\d]+(\.[\d]{2})?)` to get only `15.00` and not `15.00|GR`.

The full example would look like this:

```
Pattern.compile("^([\\d]+(\\.[\\d]{2})?)\\|(([A-Z]{2})(,[A-Z]{2})*)\\s(\".+\")?$");
```

Comment: This is the collected information:Pay
15.00
.00
GR
,MD
"Uber" .. where the user LQ is missing

Comment: You should add another group to get all users and split them by `,` if needed. I updated my regex.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main issues.

- The `ˆ` character is an accent circumflex instead of a `^` caret.
- You're not including the square brackets in the regex.

A possible solution could be like this

```
Pattern.compile("^\\[(?<number>[\\d]+(?>\\.[\\d]{2})?)\\|(?<codes>(?>[A-Z]{2},?)+)(?>\\s\\\"(?<comment>.+)\\\")?\\]$");
```

This solution also has named capturing groups which makes it nicer to specify which group you want to get value from. https://regex101.com/r/HEboNf/2

All three of the 2 letter codes are grouped in a single capturing group, you can split them in your code on the comma.

Comment: Square bracket's I only put here but is not the problem.. Removing those from ur code made it work, even tho I need to split the users string. But overall it's a very good solution and I thank you!